# profileImpl GL4bc !!! not mapped

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, graphics, opengl

OS : Linux mint :

```
uname -a
Linux akshay-mint-desktop 4.13.0-37-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 16:03:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Hello friends,

I have compiled and installed java-cef for running embedded chromium browser. Unfortunately, when I start the application, I get the following error :

Error log :

```
javax.media.opengl.GLException: X11GLXDrawableFactory - Could not initialize shared resources for :0
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:317)
    at jogamp.opengl.SharedResourceRunner.run(SharedResourceRunner.java:295)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:625)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:539)
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:293)
    ... 2 more
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: XXX0 profile[1]: GL3bc -> profileImpl GL4bc !!! not mapped** 
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.computeProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2021)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDeviceCritical(GLProfile.java:1889)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDevice(GLProfile.java:1838)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices(GLProfile.java:1807)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.access$000(GLProfile.java:77)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile$1.run(GLProfile.java:201)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton(GLProfile.java:187)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2246)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:992)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:1021)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getMaxFixedFunc(GLProfile.java:774)
    at org.cef.browser.CefBrowserOsr.createGLCanvas(CefBrowserOsr.java:124)
    at org.cef.browser.CefBrowserOsr.<init>(CefBrowserOsr.java:71)
    at org.cef.browser.CefBrowserOsr.<init>(CefBrowserOsr.java:58)
    at org.cef.browser.CefBrowserFactory.create(CefBrowserFactory.java:16)
    at org.cef.CefClient.createBrowser(CefClient.java:144)
    at org.cef.CefClient.createBrowser(CefClient.java:137)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:36)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
```

Any ideas what is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be with jogl. Apparently it needs to update the code to reflect updates in OpenGL with some GPUs, I'm affected with an AMD Polaris GPU. It is fixed in next release, but doesn't seem to have an ETA.

Here's more information (https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1357) and a patch. I am not versed in java, so I couldn't apply it.